# How to perform high precision calculations with mutable class in Java?

Tags: java

I'm designing a tool using Java 6, that will read data from Medical Devices.

Each Medical Device manufacturer implements its own Firmware/Protocol.  Vendors (like me) write their own interface that 
uses the manufacturer's firmware commands to acquire data from the Medical Device.  Most firmwares will output data in a cryptic fashion, so the vendor receiving it, is supposed to scale it by doing some calculations on it, in order to figureout the true value.

Its safe to assume that medical data precision is as important as financial data precision etc.

I've come to the conclusion of using BigDecimal to do all numerical calculations and store the final value.  I'll be receiving a new set of data almost every second, which means, I'll be doing calculations and updating the same set of values every second.  Example:Data coming across from a ventilator for each breath.

Since BigDecimal is immutable, I'm worried about the number of objects generated in the heap every second. Especially since the tool will have to scale up to read data from lets say 50 devices at the same time.

I can increase the heap size and all that, but still here's my questions....

Questions

1. Is there any mutable cousin of BigDecimal I could use?
2. Is there any existing opensource framework to do something like this?
3. Is Java the right language for this kind of functionality?
4. Should I look into Apfloat? But Apfloat is immutable too.  How about JScience?
5. Any Math library for Java I can use for high precision
6. I'm aiming for a precision of upto 10 digits only.  Dont need more than that.  So whats the best library or course of action for this type of precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that before you jump to the conclusion that BigDecimal doesn't suit your needs, that you actually profile your scenario. It is not a foregone conclusion that immutable nature is going to have a significant impact on your scenario. A modern JVM is very good at allocate and destroying large quantities of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `double` primitive type offers approximately 16 digits of decimal precision, why not just use that? Then you won't be touching the heap at all.

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage collector should do a decent enough job of cleaning the objects up, however if you still do want immutable Numbers, you can always access the back-data of BigDecimal using reflections, that way you can create a wrapper class for BigDecimal to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need 10 digits of precision you can simply use a double, which has [16 digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) of precision.

Comment: @Alex,@AaronD and @Bobby - I shouldn't have mentioned the 10 digit precision thing....I think I used incorrect phrasing.  When I google around, most people talk about inaccuracies in calculations when using float/double...so I would like to stick with BigDecimal regardless.  [ForExample](http://epramono.blogspot.com/2005/01/double-vs-bigdecimal.html)

Comment: If you really need 10 decimal digits of accuracy, you shouldn't use `double`. While `double` can reliably store 15 decimal digits, it looses precision with every operation. After only one addition, you can probably only rely on 14 digits. I guess multiplications can lose even more precision.

Answer (score -1):

You say specifically that you need only 10 significant digits. You don't say whether you're considering binary or decimal digits, but standard 64-bit IEEE floating point (Java double) offers 52 binary digits (approximately 16 decimal digits), which sounds like it more than meets your needs.

However, I do recommend that you put some thought into the numerical stability of whatever operations you apply to the input numbers. For example, Math.log() and Math.exp() can have unexpected effects depending on the range of the inputs (in some cases, you might find Math.log1p() and Math.exp1m() to be more appropriate, but again - that depends on the specific operations you're performing).

Comment: This only works if they really only need 10 decimal digits, if they meant decimal places, then `double` wouldn't work. Besides that, according to Wikipedia, you have only 15 to 17 decimal digits. (16 is an approximation, the concrete value depends on the number.) So if the value must be correct, you have only 15. Also note that this is only true, if you don't make any mathematical calculations. So even if you are only adding up two values, you should only rely on 14 digits. If you make more operations (like multiple additions), you lose even more digits.